# How to create a rounded bitmap for notification big icon in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Is there an easy Jetpack Compose way to create a circular bitmap image to show as a big icon in the notifications?

Here is how I am creating the rectangular bitmap inside a composable, but I need to convert it to a circular bitmap:

```
val myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.header)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Take a look at Coil. The first example here (https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but don't see anything there about making a circular bitmap.

Comment: There is something like `transformations(CircleCropTransformation())` in the first code example. Isn't it any helpful for your situation?